# How to install "linuxLAFFpkg"?

Tags: software-installation

The file downloaded under the name "linuxLAFFpkg.tar.bz2". The instructions on the site said open it with an unzip app, which I did. It gave me a folder called "LAFF", which contains several folders, several files whose icons are purple diamonds, two text files starting with "lib", one text file called "qt.conf", and a text file called "run.sh".

Prior posts suggest looking for a file called "INSTALL" (none here).

- I tried `xdg-open` on `run.sh` and it just opened the file in gedit.
- I tried to run the run.sh in the terminal and it gave me an error
  message. Also the post said the classical steps in installation are
  /.configure, make, and sudo make install or sudo checkinstall.

My terminal doesn't know what "configure" is.

I have plenty to learn about Ubuntu and I hope you can teach me the next few things.

Comment: If an answer helped, mark it as accepted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Comment: What was the exact errors? Are you following any instruction?

Answer (score 1):

It is actually pretty simple. All you need to do is run:

```
./run.sh
```

or

```
sudo ./run.sh
```

The computer will tell you which one to use. Just run the first one and it will give you a message like "You need Root Permissions", then run the `sudo` one.